# Fail to install Microsoft Cosmos/DocumentDB emulator docker container - unkown blob

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJhB3.jpg)I've just installed Docker for Windows on latest Windows 10 Pro. Docker starts and passes the install tests eg docker run hello-world.  However, i am unable to successfully download and run the Microsoft DocumentDB emulator. I've followed the instructions:
"Once you have Docker for Windows installed, you can pull the Emulator image from Docker Hub by running the following command from your favorite shell (cmd.exe, PowerShell, etc.)"

docker pull microsoft/azure-documentdb-emulator

From screenshot you can see that the container downloading fails with an "unknown blob" error. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you run "docker version" in cmd.exe, is the server version Linux/amd64? If so, you need to switch so that the server OS is Windows. To do that, go to the taskbar and right click the docker whale icon, and then click "Switch to Windows containers". You'll then have to restart your machine.